# two inputs in same form are conflicting

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

I have a form that contains a table. Within each row of the table are two inputs. One of them is a text input to update the quantity of items in a cart. The other input is an image. When clicked the item should be deleted. If you update the amount in the text cell and hit return, it attempts to update it AND delete it. I've dumped the variables, and the $_POST array contains both the following entries:

KEY: summary

VAL: array(3) { ["ccbna007"]=> string(1) "5" ["ccbna001"]=> string(2) "10" ["ccbna002"]=> string(2) "10" }

AND

KEY: delete

VAL: array(1) { ["ccbna007"]=> string(4) "-302" }

Can someone help me figure out how my markup is affecting my submitted variables, and in turn, how to fix the error? See the markup below. Please let me know if more information is needed.

**...inside a table within the form**

```
<form action="distro.php" method="post">

    <tr>
    <td>S/T LP</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="10" name="summary[ccbna001]" size="2"></td>
    <td>10.00</td>
    <td>
      <a>
          <input alt="Remove item from your cart" type="image" title="Remove Item" src="img/delete.gif" name="delete[ccbna001]" height="10px" width="10px">

      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

**...More rows like this one...**

```
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press <kbd>enter</kbd>, you are submitting all inputs as they fall under the same form. Make two forms and keep both inputs separate if you want them to be treated separately.

Comment: This is what I was hoping is not the case. So this means that every input needs its own form...

Comment: I believe so, unless you use some javascript/ajax. Then you could do: onsubmit="postFunction(); return false;" And in the post Function, grab the values from the quantity input and send that only.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would do it like this:

```
<form action="distro.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>S/T LP</td>
    <td>
       <input type="text" value="10" name="summary[ccbna001]" size="2">
    </td>
    <td>10.00</td>
    <td>
      <a href="delete.php?id=123" id="delete[ccbna001]" >
          <img src="img/delete.gif" alt="Remove item from your cart" 
                height="10px" width="10px"/>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><input type="sumit" value="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Because an image isnt an input, I would call a deleting script through the anchor tag.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input Under the definitions for the type attr: "A graphical submit button"

Comment: yes you can turn an input into an image, but in thats why it will POST your form which is a problem in your case. Multiple forms is really messy solution my friend

Comment: @eightArmCode for example if you wanted the submit button to be an image than that would have been fine. but not what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I do think that using the get method for the delete links is the cleanest way to do it. Now I wonder if the delete links need their own forms? Since they are submit buttons with varying destinations, can I create one form elsewhere and relate them by id?

Comment: no you wouldn't need additional form, If you simply link to the `delete.php` then you will be able to read the `id` over there

Comment: Well, I'm not linking to a different page, actually. I want to stay on the same page, but send a different GET variable (thereby changing the link) depending on which delete button is clicked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44528/discussion-between-meda-and-eightarmcode)

Answer (score 0):

Change the image input to simple image tag, then enclose it with link.
The link should guide to the script which will delete a row from your database or session.

Answer (score 0):

You should have form for every row like this:

```
<tr>
    <form action="distro.php" method="post">
        <td>S/T LP</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="10" name="summary[ccbna001]" size="2"></td>
        <td>10.00</td>
        <td>
            <a>
                <input alt="Remove item from your cart" type="image" title="Remove Item" src="img/delete.gif"
                       name="delete[ccbna001]" height="10px" width="10px">

            </a>
        </td>

        <input type="sumit" value="submit">
    </form>
</tr>
```

and so on for each row ...